# Need Order data after specific order number using zfr-shopify package

Tags: php, api, package, shopify, libraries

I have used below package to get shop order from shopify.

https://github.com/zf-fr/zfr-shopify

Now I got all orders data of store and stored in my DB. Now I need orders after specific order number.

Suppose,In my db last order number was 123 then I get all orders after order number 123.

Sample Code :

```
$shopifyClient = new ShopifyClient([
    'private_app'   => false,
    'api_key'       => 'YOUR_API_KEY',
    'access_token'  => 'MERCHANT_TOKEN',
    'shop'          => 'merchant.myshopify.com',
    'version'       => '2019-04'
]);
$orders = $shopifyClient->getOrders();
```

Now, I don't know how to pass argument inside that function and achieve my above requirement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the repository README, it says that you pass arguments as a first parameter, in a type of array.

So try this to get orders after a specific ID:

```
$orders = $shopifyClient->getOrders([
  'since_id' => 123
]);
```

Comment: yes it is working. @Vladimir. Thanks :)
My i know is there any proper documentation for above query builder. If so then can you please provide me its link. I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: I believe you can pass there any arguments that Shopify API accepts. If I were the package owner I would do this way. The `GET /orders` endpoint reference you can find here: https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/orders/order?api[version]=2020-04#index-2020-04. Just try to use parameters listed there.